# What is the average fuel economy of a 100 cc bike if I ride above 50 km/h?

Tags: mileage, hero-honda

I have a Hero Passion Pro and I get an average of 60 km/L since I ride my bike with fuel economy in mind (i.e. between 40 and 49 km/h). What I want to know is what would be the average if rode at 80 to 100 km/h?

The reason I am asking this question is the company claims that this bike will have an average of 84 km/L and never gives the detailed information in what way you can ride. I mean what mixture of highway, city, stop-and-go traffic.

Comment: Depends on so many things : weight of driver , a passenger, uphill or flat terrain, how many other cars etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Fuel economy and mileage aren't static fixed things. You say you drive 40-49 km/h and get 60 km/L, I could ride your bike at the same speeds and get 40 km/L. You see, when I accelerate, I accelerate like I really need to get to where I'm going because I badly have to pee.

Acceleration, not speed, as well as air temperature, air pressure, air moisture and general condition of the bike are what will dictate most of your fuel economy and mileage. You want to know how much mileage you can get driving at 80-100 km/h? Do this:

1. Find 2 fuel stations near a highway where you can drive 80-100 km/L
2. The fuel stations need to be far enough apart that you will use enough fuel to notice when you fill up.
3. If you can't find a 2nd station that is convenient, just run an itinerary that will bring you back to the first station. Avoid traffic lights and avoid stopping. Look for an itinerary or a highway where there are interchanges or an easy way to turn around.
4. Ride to that first station when there isn't traffic on the highway
5. Fill up your fuel tank completely
6. Reset your trip odometer (if you have one) or take a picture of your main odometer.
7. Ride on the highway at constant speed between 80-100 km/h
8. When you are done, fill-up your fuel tank again. How much fuel you buy the 2nd time is how much fuel you used on your highway trip. Divide your distance covered by your fuel used, and now you know, with YOU riding on THAT highway in THAT weather what your fuel economy is.

Comment: Its a kind of practical needs to be done i wants the estimate about how much a 100cc on 80 kmph tp 100 kmph gives average